# Drupal 6: Extremely-Annoyingly slow although devel (&all development modules) are disabled!

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, hosting, module, performance

I'm new at Drupal.

I use Hostgator and working on my first Drupal project, at the begninning everything was fine. but later site has started loading extremely slow! I even needed to contact to HostGator, and they restarted the apache. than it was fine for 10 mins, and same again now!

Sometimes it give mysql errors like **The mysqli error was: Too many connections.**
Sometimes just go to **Drupal's Ste Off-line page**! and sometimes site works well with few minutes

I use only standard modules. list below;

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100601-p8hcdepfacgm8ubtmk1a9s643i.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100601-p8hcdepfacgm8ubtmk1a9s643i.jpg)

any advise? Appreciate helps!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just spoke to Hostgator Support, they advised me to go for better hosting plan which will cost much more! they wanted me to go for Dedicated that I can not afford!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have caching turned on you should at least enable core caching. Also, see make sure poormanscron isn't set too high and since `HostGator` has `cPanel`, you may just want to disable that and enable `cron` via `cPanel`. Other than that it could be `HostGator` having settings too low for your site.

If that doesn't work, Go for Drupal customized hosting which includes Drupal security updates.

Comment: i upgraded the hostgator hosting plan. from baby plan to dedicated server. and now everything is working like wind :) ...